# Express nested field in Spring Data MongoDB aggregation $project

Tags: mongodb, spring-data, spring-data-mongodb

This query generate a object with the key/value inside works as i expect

```
db.empdetails.aggregate( [ { $project: { reportInformationMap: { valu1: 1 } } } ] );
```

So in spring data i do:

```
Aggregation.project("reportInformationMap.valu1")
```

Spring data generate  something like this:

```
{ "aggregate" : "__collection__" , "pipeline" : [ { "$project" : {  "valu1" : "$reportInformationMap.valu1"}}
```

it work but gimme `valu1` as root value. i need it as nest value of `reportInformationMap`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to use the `ProjectionOperation.ProjectionOperationBuilder.nested` method for this (`nested` defines the nested field binding for the field):

Here is an example with the following input document:

```
{ "name" : { "first" : "John", "last" : "Doe" } }
```

The code:

```
ProjectionOperation projection = Aggregation.project().and("name").nested(Fields.fields("name.first"))

Aggregation agg = newAggregation(projection);
AggregationResults<Document> results = mongoTemplate.aggregate(agg, "test", Document.class);
results.forEach(doc -> System.out.println(doc.toJson()));
```

The output (projected):

```
{ "name": {"first": "John"} }
```